# Making Ajax request to php script but nothing being output

Tags: php, ajax

I'm performing an `Ajax` request to a `php` file called `save_tags.php` this is the content of the file:

```
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $type = $_POST['type'];
     $tags = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tags'])); //Should be an Array but is a String...
     $removeTags = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['removeTags']));

     //Type can be company, contact, column, supplement, programme. 
     if($type == 'company'){
        $tagObject = new DirectoryCompany($id);
    }elseif($type == 'contact'){
        $tagObject = new DirectoryContact($id);
    }elseif($type == 'column'){
        $tagObject = new Column($id);
    }elseif($type == 'supplement'){
        $tagObject = new Supplement($id);
    }elseif($type == 'programme'){
        $tagObject = new Programme($id);
    }elseif($type == 'list'){
        $tagObject = new DirectoryContactList($id);
    }

     //Add and Remove Tags by looping through the Arrays.  
     foreach($tags as $tag){
         $tagObject->addTag($tag, $id); 

     }
     foreach($removeTags as $tag){
         $tagObject->deleteTag($tag, $id);   
     }

     //Get the tags associated with the object
    $tagarray = $tagObject->getTags($id); 

    // Add Tags to All contacts on the list
    $tagObject->getAllcontactsAndAddTags($id);

    //Build HTML output
    $output  = "<ul>";
    foreach($tagarray as $tag){
        $output .= "<li>". $tag .'<a href="#">[X]</a>'."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    echo $output;
?>
```

The purpose of the file is to apply the tags a user has checked and apply them to the object being worked on. Currently the above code is working, as in the tags are being applied and saved. however what is not working is that the `$output` variable is not being `echoed` and I can't figure out why.

Also when I check my console via the browser window I can see that there was a `500` error when requesting the file.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: the problem most likely lies in your javascript or htaccess file. if its 500 error then, this script isn't even running. so you should as add your js script to this problem

Comment: I'm not sure it's `htaccess` as it is finding the file. I'll review the `js` though

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: do you post `$_POST['tags']` as an array value ? I made some test with your code, looks perfectly fine if you add array values to `$tags` and `$removeTags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to put a few var_dumps here and there to see if you data is correct. An statuscode 500 means that there was most likely a fatal error in your script. This can be either in this php file or in one of your classes.
Most likely you will find the answer in a few minutes. To check if your script even works, try to echo some simple like "test" and comment everything else.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the response. I've already `echoed` some static text and it is being displayed when I view the response. I've also done a few var_dumps and it would appear that the data is correct. I'll look into it further though.

Comment: It was in fact an error within my php code. Thank you for help

Comment: i work alot with ajax myself so its a pain in the ass to debug. pritty much the only way to debug it is to vardump alot of data and look if its correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` this is tag html, check source page

and check alert(data)

```
$.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: 'url',
                    data: { },  
                    success: function(data) {alert(data)}
                });

$output  = "<ul>";
    foreach($tagarray as $tag){
        $output .= "<li>". $tag .'<a href="#">[X]</a>'."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    echo $output;
```

if $tagarray is null echo = `<ul></ul>` invisible on the page

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: I edited and add if $tagarray is null echo = <ul></ul> invisible on the page

Answer (score 1):

500 errors usually means that there's something wrong with your php code. Make sure that the code doesn't error out. Try to go to it in your browser and confirm that there are no errors.